# Eigen sparse matrix multiplications seem to compute full matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am trying to multiply 2 eigen sparse matrices. The code is as follows:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> SpMat;
SpMat mat_1;
mat_1.resize(n_e, n_e);
... Fill the matrix. It is sparse

SpMat mat_2;
mat_1.resize(n_e, n_e);
... Fill the matrix. It is sparse

SpMat mat_3 = (mat_1 * mat_2).pruned();
```

This works fine for small matrices but for larger matrices, it just runs and runs and ten crashes with a seg fault. The same thing in Matlab takes a couple of seconds. So, I wonder if it is trying to keep the full matrix somewhere. If it does, that is really bad! I looked at the documentation and doing this is what it suggested to prune the matrix on the fly.

Comment: Ok, it seems I should not use pruned(). It works well without it but I have no idea why as the documentation clearly states to use it: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html 
See matrix product section...

Comment: Have you also tried `.pruned(SOME_SMALL_NUMBER)` instead? Maybe there are large rounding errors here which prevent `pruned()` to run efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the document is sightly confusing for me at least.

the way to do it is simply:

```
SpMat mat_3 = mat_1 * mat_2
```

No dense matrix is created along the way.

Eigen rocks!